# Can I have a critique of this set theory proof/Advice on a similar proof?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This is an exercise from Mendelson's Introduction to Topology. The first part is to prove, given a function $\ f:A \rightarrow B$, that $\ X \subset f^{-1}(f(X))$ for all $\ X \subset A$. Here's my proof:

By the definition of the image of a set, $\ x \in X \implies f(x) \in f(X)$. Since $f$ associates with each $\ x \in A$ an $\ f(x) \in B$ and $\ X \subset A$, $\ f(X) \subset B$. By the definition of the inverse of a set, $\ f(x) \in f(X) \implies x \in f^{-1}f(X)$. Thus $\ X \subset f^{-1}f(X).$

My problem with this proof is that it hinges on the fact that $f(X)$ is a subset of $B$, and my reasoning for this in the above proof seems shaky. Is it possible to prove a subset relation that way?

The next part of the exercise is to prove that, given $\ f:A \rightarrow B$, $\ f(f^{-1}(X)) \subset Y$ for each $\ Y \subset B$. It seems that, to even get started, I would need to assume that $f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(X))$, which I'm not sure I can do. However, I can't think of another way to start correctly. Any advice on either of these problems would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine: $f(x)\in B$ for each $x\in X$, so automatically $f[X]\subseteq B$. In the second part of the exercise I suspect that you meant that you’re to prove that $f[f^{-1}[Y]]\subseteq Y$ for each $Y\subseteq B$. For this you want to start with an arbitrary $b\in f[f^{-1}[Y]]$ and show that $b\in Y$. Since $b\in f[f^{-1}[Y]]$, you know that there is an $a\in f^{-1}[Y]$ such that $f(a)=b$, so ... ?